# Value Null from Angular service call

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I'm getting null for my fileName value on the controller. I have this code from my component. Using Angular 7 and .net core 2.1

```
handleFileInput(event) {

const file = event.target.files[0];
this.fileName = file.name;

console.log('This file - ' + this.fileName);

this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.fileService.getHeaders().subscribe((data: IApiHelper) => {
    this.fileService.createHeader(data);
    this.fileService.saveFileProperties(this.fileName).subscribe(s => {
      console.log('this is inside subscribe - ' + s);
      this.fileName = s;        
    },
      (error) => { console.log(error); }
    );
  });
})
```

}

This is code from service:

```
saveFileProperties(fileName: string ) {return this.http.post<string>('/api/aspera/SaveFileToDatabase',fileName, this.httpOptions);
```

}

My controller expects a string :

```
public IActionResult SaveFileToDatabase(string fileName){
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the POST should retrieve the fileName from the body of the message using the FromBody attribute:

```
public IActionResult SaveFileToDatabase([FromBody]string fileName){
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an object with `fileName` property

```
this.fileService.saveFileProperties({fileName: this.fileName}).subscribe( //..
```